# redirect from http to https and without www to www does not work correctly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file but parts of the site are accessible without "www". How can I change my htaccess so that all urls of my site are only accessible with "www"?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i hope somebody can help?

edit: when i use this rule from an other post:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

the problem is not solved. All the pages are working correctly with https and with www. But all images in the folder wp-content/uploads are still accessible without www and with http. The site is hochzeitshaus-leipzig.de

i dont see the mistake...

Comment: Does `wp-content` or `wp-content/uploads` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: yes there is another htaccess with this code:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: can i delete this htaccess?

Comment: is one htaccess in the root enough

Comment: ok when i delete the htaccess in the the folder i works .-) do i need a second htaccess?

Comment: niw i see it does not work... now i have only one htaccess in the root directory with the code above. when i check one images like this: https://www.hochzeitshaus-leipzig.de/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Goldkarte-zum-verschenken.jpg it is accessible without www and with www. and the http version redirects to an 404 error...

Comment: it was my mistake i looked wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120632/discussion-between-tom84-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Check RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... no other effect. when i open an image it is accessible with www without www with http and with https. take a look http://www.hochzeitshaus-leipzig.de/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Goldkarte-zum-verschenken-495x325.jpg also strange is, that the version without https has an other favicon...